# How to make UI elements load without freezing? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, freeze

I have a treeview and a textbox. As I type in the text box it updates the tree view in real time (filtering by what I type and matching against the objects in the tree view).

The problem is it starts freezing a bit as I'm typing in the box. ie. while the treeview is updating the text box freezes. I have put the logic that populates the treeview in another thread hoping this would make it run a bit faster - which it did, but not enough. I believe it is the actual UI updating which is causing the responsiveness to diminish.

What are some ways that I can tackle this problem? Is it possible to have different UI elements (in this case, the treeview and the textbox) handled in different threads - rather than just the logic which is the case now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that only one UI thread exists!

A possible solution to your problem is to filter the treeview after a few milliseconds after the user has made ​​a text input.

Another possibility is to make the filtering in a separate task and the result of the Treview reassign.

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to make more than one UI thread exist or is that a limitation of .NET? What do you mean by making the filtering a separate task? At the moment the filtering (searching through the treeview) is done in another thread. It's just the actual updating of the treeview that seems to slow things down. Cheers

Comment: @theqs1000 it exists only one ui thread by the limitation of .NET. you can try using a CollectionViewSource (try look at the msdn help) to filter your treeview or only filtering your source collection in a seperate thread (task) and after this put the result to the treeview (so the treeview is not freezing), hope that helps